# Why are they avoiding showing Arys Oakheart's face?

Tags: character, production, game-of-thrones, casting

*Game of Thrones* edited out a lot of characters/stories from books like Lady Stoneheart (which is [discussed here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74865/is-lady-stonehearts-absence-from-the-show-explained)) and even shortened the stories of a few characters like Cold Hands (which is further [discussed here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/why-was-the-character-coldhands-not-introduced-in-season-4-when-he-was-in-the-b)). And same the happened to many Dorne characters and story arcs.

But one character who had a significant story in the Dorne arc in the book did appear but is never called by that name and didn't even show his face.

[image]

[Arys Oakheart](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Arys_Oakheart)

His task is to protect Myrcella Baratheon in Dorne but even after

> the death of Myrcella Baratheon

he didn't even show his face. What was the reason for not showing his face? Did they even cast anyone for that role or was it always played by some random extra?

Comment: Because the story is too long to fit the TV show, like with the other edited out characters? What's special about this one that the questions you cite don't answer?

Comment: @Luciano the didn't edited out that character but placed him in multiple spaces without showing his face

Comment: Yup, so maybe he will still show up later in the season? We can't be sure until it's over. The writers might be keeping him around for another story arc, or just ignoring him til the end...

Comment: @AnkitSharma If he's never called by name, and never shows his face, how do you know it's the same character? It doesn't necessarily make sense for Myrcella to go to Dorne without being accompanied by a member of the Kingsguard, so they have a nameless/faceless Kingsguard.

Comment: @Luciano There are only four episodes left in this season, and only six in the final one. They're killing off characters left and right. Do you really expect them to introduce a brand-new character at this stage? A character which in the books is Dorne-exclusive, and Dorne is basically done and dusted in GoT.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I don't expect anything, just pointing out reasons why the character would be "invisible" until now. I do believe that the character is out because he was written out of the show / his role is not as important as in the books for whatever production reasons.

Comment: *But why do they always hide his face???* Nobody does that, even when a book character has been written out of a show. That is strange, and still a good question.

Comment: Maybe the "faceless" aspect is actually intended and thematic. This part of the story also lines up with ARYa's Braavosi "Faceless Men" plots (and would of also lined up with Jyene Pole switch out and eventually Young Griff)---the exploration of identity is surely one rather well-explored concept in the books, something minimized in the TV show by cutting those other things out. But maybe because of the name similarity on Arya with Arys, they intentionally teased him without letting them see his face as a kind of "in-joke" juxtaposition for novel fans????

Answer (score 1):

I compared the [Arys_Oakheart GOT Fandom](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Arys_Oakheart) page, which indicates which episodes the character appeared in  with  imdb.com's data. I wasn't able to find the GOT character Arys Oakheart listed in the  film credits for any featured episode *or* the primary list of the [imdb.com's GOT Full Cast & Crew](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) . It stands to reason that if they had cast an actor to this part, the contract would have included listing that actor in the cast. Since they appear to have "no one" playing the part, you have a valid assumption that the part is played by random "extras".